# Matlab FTP file read issue

Tags: data-transfer, ftp

I am trying to download a directory from ftp location and storing in shared location. This folder is around 10 MB. The download is taking more than **15 mins**

I am doing this as want to perform some checks on the file data that I will be getting from ftp location. 
I am using mget() for download

ftpConnection = ftp(a,v,c);
%if(exist('S:\xpath\,'file'))
 %   rmdir('S:xpath\','s');
%end
%Read and Download files from the local folder
tic
mget(ftpConnection,'Inbox','S:\ypath');

toc
%ftp Close
close(ftpConnection);
uiout='File downloaded!';

I am using Matlab R2015b on windows 7 OS.

Any suggestions on how to speed up the process?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with Apple software or hardware

Comment: Also, every time I have to download at the same location, which gives error 'cannot overwrite'. I am removing the directory if it exists but its again taking lot of time to delete and download the data...any suggestion to speed the process?

Comment: How about reading the comment made and also read how to respond on this site - that should have been an edit not a comment - help is at the top right